# Issue with Chrome.dll: IsEnclaveTypeSupported Entry Point Not Found

Tags: google-chrome

I'm having a problem with Google Chrome on my computer. When I try to open it, I get an error message that says something about a file called `chrome.dll`. The error message says:

```
 "The procedure entry point IsEnclaveTypeSupported could not be found in 
the dynamic link library C:\Program 
Files\Google\Application\117.0.5938.63\chrome.dll."
```

I've tried reinstalling Chrome, but the problem is still there. I'm using version `117.0.5938.63` of Chrome. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1I1Z.jpg)

Chrome install and not opening

Answer (score 0):

You can check the official update here:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/234701391?hl=en

I suspect that the problem is related to old Windows. My college computer face the same issue. 2 of them.

I try to update the windows on 1 of that computer and it's doing fine. BUt it's really slow. If there is fix for this problem, i'll rollback to Win 10, 2015 version

Comment: They finally fixed it. If you can get to a new 117, you should be good to go.
Chrome is up to date
Version 117.0.5938.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in all Windows 10 machines, do not update chrome to 117 if you can, or rollback to 116.
For some reason, google removed the thread with the description, it's no longer available here https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/234701391?hl=en

Comment: Appears to be just win 10, 2015 LTSB.

Comment: I can also reproduce the problem on LTSB 2015. It does not appear on LTSB 2016 for me.